# How to send push notification from web to iOS and android device using AWS SNS in Laravel 5.1?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, laravel-5.1

I have coded like,

```
$sns = App::make('aws')->createClient('sns');

    $data = json_encode([
        'APNS' => ['apns' => [
                'alert' => $message
            ]
        ]
    ]);

    Log::info($data);

    $sns->publish(array(
        'Message' => $data,
        'TargetArn' => "arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:360542326270:endpoint/APNS_SANDBOX/Testtest/20a75cd1-da25-3331-8126-4db497cbdd5e"
    ));
```

I'am getting the error as below:

```
[Aws\Sns\Exception\SnsException]
```

Error executing "Publish" on "https://sns.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: `POST https://sns.us-east-1.amazonaws.com` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:

```
  <Type>Sender</Type>                                                                                                                                                                 
  <Code>InvalidPara (truncated...)
```

InvalidParameter (client): Invalid parameter: TargetArn Reason: No endpoint found for the target arn specified -

```
  <Type>Sender</Type>                                                                                                                                                                 
  <Code>InvalidParameter</Code>                                                                                                                                                       
  <Message>Invalid parameter: TargetArn Reason: No endpoint found for the target arn specified</Message>                                                                              

<RequestId>18937e90-5453-5e30-bf89-315a59c3f2af</RequestId>
```

[GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException]
  Client error: `POST https://sns.us-east-1.amazonaws.com` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:

```
  <Type>Sender</Type>                                                                             
  <Code>InvalidPara (truncated...)
```

Can anyone help me to find the solution? Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated the config file with my AWS account Key and secret in the config/aws.php file by following the link 
`https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel`. By this, it gets worked. Previously, I have updated in my .env file. Now, it works well.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [this forum post](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=478775). Basically, the issue stems from the fact that your Topic/Target arn is for **us-west-2**. But by default your SNS client is pointing to **us-east-1**. You need to call `setRegion` on snsClient.

This is how the post says to do it:

```
snsClient.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2));
```

You'll probably have to translate into the PHP laravel specific client you are using.